# Convert .csv into .xlsx (JavaScript/CMD/Notepad)

Tags: javascript, csv, notepad, file-conversion

I have a script (JS) which returns me a .csv-file (comma separated). It works perfectly fine. I can convert the .csv into a .xmls via Excel manually. However I would like this to be done by a script/command line.

Is something like this possible? I basically want the .csv (see example below) to be structured in columns and rows.

Example of my csv (which should be displayed in rows and columns):

a,b,c,d,e

1,2,3,4,5

6,7,8,9,10

11,12,13,14,15

Thanks in advance and have a good day :)

Comment: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: Hmmm, CSV is a perfectly valid file format to work with Excel, and your example should be displayed in lines and columns out of the box (although most features we take for granted, i.e. persistent column size, can't be saved to CSV). Is it just the formatting that is problematic? Because in that case we'd much better investigate why your CSV isn't properly displayed by Excel rather than how to convert it to .xlsx